# What happens when you have the same class twice in a war deployed in tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, classloader

What happens when you have the *same compiled class* twice in a war deployed in tomcat?
(I know it's not a good practice and so on, but what happens behind the scene?)

Are there chances of nasty side-effects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would expect the behaviour is the same as anywhere else you have that situation.

The first class found by the class loader will be used, the other will be ignored.

Comment: are there chances of nasty side-effects?

Comment: Well one class won't be used and the other will...which means potentially some libraries/whatever will get a class they aren't expecting... so yes.... What more side effects did you have in mind?

Comment: it is the same class, I mean the same compiled class included twice. I do not know what can happen - that's why I'm asking...:)

Comment: Fret not. Nothing to worry about.

Comment: If they really are identical then as @TracySnell says nothing to worry about. If one is a different version of the same class (i.e. more recent library) then you do need to be a bit careful.

Answer (score 6):

If you have one class is in WEB-INF/classes and the other in a jar, the one in WEB-INF/classes will have priority.

If the two classes are in a jar, then one of them will be taken and the other ignored. The one that gets chosen depends on the classloader implementation details and can be different from environment to environment.

So the right class might be chosen in development, and the wrong one in production causing problems that are can be hard to debug. The only way to solve this problem is to remove all duplicate classes from the WAR, this way only one class will always be chosen everywhere.

If you want to detect all these types of duplicates, have a look at this tool I wrote, [JHades](http://jhades.org). It includes a [command line tool](http://jhades.org/documentation.html#warreport) that lists all duplicates in the WAR:

```
java -jar jhades-standalone-report.jar path/to/war/webapp.war

>>>> Jar overlap report:

poi-3.5-FINAL-20090928.jar overlaps with poi-3.7-20101029.jar - total overlapping classes: 990
xercesImpl-2.7.0.jar overlaps with xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar - total overlapping classes: 867
xalan-2.6.0.jar overlaps with xalan-2.7.1.jar - total overlapping classes: 711
bcel-5.2.jar overlaps with xalan-2.7.1.jar - total overlapping classes: 361
xml-apis-2.9.1.jar overlaps with xml-apis.jar - total overlapping classes: 301
jasperreports-applet-3.7.1.jar overlaps with jasperreports-javaflow-3.7.1.jar - total overlapping classes: 254
jasperreports-3.7.1.jar overlaps with jasperreports-applet-3.7.1.jar - total overlapping classes: 254
...

Total number of classes with more than one version: 6169
```

Comment: I am not sure what right class means in this context? can you please explain? is there a difference, even if its the same compiled class? if yes - can you please detail the issue? P.S. Thank you so much for the tool recommendation

Comment: If it's the same compiled class, then there is no difference, because no matter which class file get's chosen the result will be the same. What happens as well it that there are completely different versions of the same class, meaning if one is 1.2 and the other is 2.0, there is no guarantee which one is chosen. If there are two different versions of the same class, then some analysis needs to be done to determine if one of the two satisfies all the application dependencies and delete the other one, in order to be sure that always the same version of the class gets read.