# Spring logs not coming machine specific

Tags: java, tomcat, java-8, slf4j, logback

I am using a `spring maven tomcat8 java8` stack. The problem I am facing is that logs are not getting generated on certain machines. I am using `slf4j-logback` combination for logging. The problem has surfaced when I am trying to move my stack from `java7` to `java8`.

Here is my `logback.xml:`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<configuration>
    <appender name="dal"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>/var/log/dal/dal.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- daily rollover -->
            <fileNamePattern>/var/log/dal/dal-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.gz</fileNamePattern>
            <!-- keep 30 days' worth of history -->
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <append>true</append>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>[%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %thread %-5level %C:%L] %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>[%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %thread %-5level %C:%L] %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="email-appender" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SMTPAppender">
        <to></to>
        <from></from>
        <subject>API Logs - Error while sending notification</subject>
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <pattern>[%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %thread %-5level %C:%L] %msg%n</pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="dal" />
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Using this, I expect to get logs at two places, at custom location `/var/log/dal/dal.log` and in `catalina.out`

Here are a few relevant details of the server where logs are getting generated:

OS:

```
apache-tomcat-8.0.15 $ uname -a
Linux azi 3.2.0-74-generic #109-Ubuntu SMP Tue Dec 9 16:45:49 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

MVN:

```
apache-tomcat-8.0.15 $ mvn -version
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=1024m; support was removed in 8.0
Apache Maven 3.0.4
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.8.0_25, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.2.0-74-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

Tomcat:

```
apache-tomcat-8.0.15 $ bin/version.sh 
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.15
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.15
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.15/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/
Using CLASSPATH:       /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.15/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.15/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Server version: Apache Tomcat/8.0.15
Server built:   Nov 2 2014 19:25:20 UTC
Server number:  8.0.15.0
OS Name:        Linux
OS Version:     3.2.0-74-generic
Architecture:   amd64
JVM Version:    1.8.0_25-b17
JVM Vendor:     Oracle Corporation
```

JAVA:

```
apache-tomcat-8.0.15 $ java -version
java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)
```

Permission:

```
ls -al /var/log/dal/
total 72
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root  4096 Dec 22 19:50 .
drwxrwxrwx 4 root root  4096 Oct 21 09:47 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 60925 Dec 22 20:38 dal.log
```

Here are the details for the server where I am not getting any log:
OS:

```
sysadmin@ip-172-30-0-26:/opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.15$ uname -a
Linux ip-172-30-0-26 3.13.0-29-generic #53-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 4 21:00:20 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

MVN:

```
sysadmin@ip-172-30-0-26:/opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.15$ mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.2.2 (45f7c06d68e745d05611f7fd14efb6594181933e; 2014-06-17T19:21:42+05:30)
Maven home: /opt/apache-maven-3.2.2
Java version: 1.8.0_25, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /opt/jdk1.8.0_25-linux-x64/java-linux-x64/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.13.0-29-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

Tomcat:

```
sysadmin@ip-172-30-0-26:/opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.15$ sudo bin/version.sh 
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.15
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.15
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.15/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr
Using CLASSPATH:       /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.15/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.15/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Server version: Apache Tomcat/8.0.15
Server built:   Nov 2 2014 19:25:20 UTC
Server number:  8.0.15.0
OS Name:        Linux
OS Version:     3.13.0-29-generic
Architecture:   amd64
JVM Version:    1.8.0_25-b17
JVM Vendor:     Oracle Corporation
```

JAVA:

```
sysadmin@ip-172-30-0-26:/opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.15$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)
```

Permission:

```
sysadmin@ip-172-30-0-26:/opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.15$ ls -al /var/log/dal/
total 8
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 Dec 22 19:48 .
drwxrwxrwx 4 root root 4096 Dec 22 19:48 ..
```

Another thing of note can be the fact that when I do `System.out.println("msg")`, `"msg"` goes into `catalins.out` on both servers. And If I change permission of `/var/log/dal` on the machine logs are getting generated, logs still get generated in `catalina.out`. So this shouldn't be related to permissions.

I have tried copying war file from one server to another and didn't find any change in behavior. So, this shouldn't be related to `maven`. Tomcat and Java versions are same. Can this be related to OS?

**UPDATE**: When I run my application using `mvn clean tomcat7:run`, I get logs on all servers. So problem seems to be related to tomcat8. I have even tried copying tomcat8 from one server to another. It didn't help.

Comment: Couple of questions - If you downgrade jdk to 7 on the machine where the logs are not getting generated, do the logs show up? Can you verify if the user that is running tomcat has permissions in the log folder i.e. /var/log/dal/dal.log?

Comment: logs were getting generated everywhere  when the whole stack was running on java7... but i haven't tries downgrading... will try and let you know soon... updating permission part in the question itself

Comment: we have also migrated from tomcat7 to tomcat8 along with java8 migration... so when i tried reverting down to java7, logs didn't come up with java7-tomcat8 combo but started getting generated with java7-tomcat7 combo... but as is evident in the question, tomcat version is same on both the servers

Comment: To narrow down the issue I would suggest trying out two things - Running a standalone application with just slf4j and logback libraries (on java7 and java8). No tomcat in this test. Next would be try out java8-tomcat7 combo so confirm that the issue is with tomcat 8 migration and not with java 8.

Comment: @AndyDufresne i have updated the question with some details... i can't check java8-tomcat7 combo because the tomcat7 version I was using along with java7 had some issue with java8 and hence I decided to move to tomcat8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the case of slf4j identifying multiple bindings in classpath. In such scenarios, slf4j chooses the binding pretty much [randomly](http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings). In my case, this was happening because `slf4j-log4j12` binding was available through `solr-core`. To remove this, I had to exclude this explicitly:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
        <artifactId>solr-core</artifactId>
        <version>${solr.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure there are no other [slf4j bindings](http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings) on the classpath (e.g., in the tomcat).

Comment: you are disagreeing with what slf4j jas to say about this http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings

Comment: Yes, I disagree. I think it shall be as stated by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21062102/what-happens-when-you-have-the-same-class-twice-in-a-war-deployed-in-tomcat

Comment: i don't think the two situations are the same

Comment: The bridge between slf4j-api jar and the different impl-jars is realized per org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder. A class with this full name is present in each impl-jar, always with corresponding content, and gets accessed in normal way (no reflection or custom classloading involved). IMHO that is exactly the case linked in my previous comment.